# run Process in Java

Tags: java, process

in my Java Application i start a postgres process to backup my database.

```
       Thread thread = new Thread(() ->{
       Process p;
       try{
           p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c pg_dump -v -a -d "+database+" -h "+server+" -p "+port+" -U "+user+" -n public > " + file.getPath());
           p.waitFor();
       }catch(Exception e){
           return false;
       }
       });
```

This works and the backup File was created. But the File size is 0KB while my Application is running. After i close the Java App - the backup file have its normal size.

I dont get it where the Problem is

Comment: Please elaborate more your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry but its hard to me to explain this right.

in my application i try to create a Database dumpfile using pg_dump from PostgreSQL. If i start the dump process then the file will be create after i close the whole application.

i hope i explain it understandable

i tried to predefine the path to file. but it was the same error. I also used the ProcessBuilder intead.

The Problem was that i used the -v Option in the pg_dump command. Without this Option it works fine and the file will be created immediately.

It is option for verbose output. Here is my final Method which works fine:

```
                Process process = new ProcessBuilder("pg_dump", "-a", "-d", database, "-h", server, "-p", port, "-U", user, "-f", file.getPath()).start();
                process.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that it probably has something to do with the `file` and the way you handle it (my guess is based on `file.getPath()` in your code).

However, you haven't posted the whole code ... So, The the only thing I can do is guess.

Try the same code with predefined file name (lets say `c:\\myfilename.dmp`).

e.g.
`p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c pg_dump -v -a -d "+database+" -h "+server+" -p "+port+" -U "+user+" -n public >  c:\\myfilename.dmp"`

How does it behave ?